# How does 2 domains on dedicated IP's sharing the same backend affect the ranking?

Tags: pagerank, ip-address, multiple-domains, local-seo

I have two Domains, both with dedicated IP's, with a service acting location based.

The two domain-names have simple to remember name-pattern going like `##servicedescription##france.com` and `##servicedescription##germany.com` with the main keyword at the first position in the domain-names.

Now, I could easily copy the CMS and servicesoftware on each hosting plan but I want the system to stay maintainable. Thus, I want both domains share the same backend with slightly different content. Both websites are displayed in english as the default language.

Does this in any way affect the ranking and how can I optimize this constellation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing the back-end is the right idea. You don't want to constantly have to upgrade packages on multiple domains. Maybe you have your own engine to drive multiple sites. That gives you ultimate flexibility.

On the face of it, there is no reason why sharing the back-end should affect your sites' rankings. However, rankings can be affected by perverse side-effects. Since the same server is serving the pages on multiple sites, if there is competition for CPU, memory, database access, your sites could slow down. Load speed affects rankings. Until you hit really large traffic, this will not be an issue.

My main concern for your rankings would not be about the IPs or the back-end, but about any [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en). If large blobs of the same text is served for different domains, Google is not going to like that.

Comment: Even on massive load the server can handle it since it is not a cheap vserver or anything like that and the engine is developed by me with main focus on high performance. Does at maximum 5% of identical strings, which will be names of links and very few headlines, be counted as duplicate content since the link you provided talks about "largely identical" content?

Comment: @QQping Congratulations on developing your own engine. I wouldn't worry about 5%. That's similar to what many big sites have for duplicated introductions etc. Also since some of it is for navigation, you can alert engines by using the nav tag.